# Вывести все теги категории

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Возникла нелегкая задача вывести теги, посты которых принадлежат определенной категории. Некое пояснение таблиц

> Таблица term_taxonomy - это объяснение к каждому термину - чем он
>   является - тегом, категорией и тд. Таблица term_relationships -
>   указатель кому, какой термин принадлежит. Таблица terms - это термины
>   (теги, категории и тд) и таблица posts - собственно сами посты. .

Это закос под wp - я в курсе/)) но зато удобно. Пример таблиц http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d765c

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7d765c/7

Comment: повис на 20К+ записях )))

Comment: я идиот забыл сделать foregin key )))